# Stream video from Device to Server

Tags: linux, network-programming, raspberry-pi, vlc

I am looking to setup a server-client video streaming architecture. The plan is to have a server running and n number of device-clients ( ip devices with cameras, raspberrypi with camera ) connect to the server and create their channel for streaming live video to that server.
After a lot of googling I came across many solutions all differing from my requirements in many ways, the most common one being that way device-clients and the server interact.
**My requirement** is that device-clients be the first to make contact and connect to the server rather than the other way round and server be open to receiving authentication requests from n number of such device-clients.

Comment: Streaming is not simple and there are many different protocols and technologies in use (RTSP, RTMP, RTP/UDP, MJPEG, H.264, HLS, and the list goes on and on). You need to narrow the scope of your question and project for you to have success with this endeavor.

Comment: Edited. Narrowed it down to current requirement as per your request.